# Stuck on zyBooks Lab 3.1.3

Tags: python

```
# Read a value from a user and store the value in first_name
first_name = input('Eric')
whole_number = input('12')
plural_noun = input('cars')
generic_location = input('Chipotle')


# TODO: Type your code to read three more values here.


# Output a short story using the four input values. Do not modify the code below.
print(first_name, 'buys', whole_number, 'different types of', plural_noun, 'at',   generic_location)
```

This is what I have and I'm unsure how how to fix it to have it make the correct output.

I tried altering the inputs or getting them to read different variables, I'm just very new and unsure of where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The string passed to *input()* is merely a prompt. The return value from *input()* is whatever was available on the standard input stream

Answer (score -1):

Input is automatically stored in the variable where it is called, such as "first_name", which you can read whenever you use it:

```
#Read a value from a user and store the value in first_name
first_name = input('Enter a name: ')
whole_number = input('Enter an integer: ')
plural_noun = input('Enter a noun in its plural form: ')
generic_location = input('Enter a location: ')
# Output a short story using the four input values.
print(first_name, 'buys', whole_number, 'different types of', plural_noun, 'at',   generic_location)
```

You can also do the last part like:

```
print({} 'buys' {} 'different types of' {}, 'at' {}.format(first_name, whole_number, plural_noun, generic_location))
```

If you wanted the sentence to use the words "Eric", "12", "cars", and "Chipotle", you can just define them as normal variables, not input.

```
first_name = 'Eric'
whole_number = '12'
plural_noun = 'cars'
generic_location = 'Chipotle'
```